# Issue with rendering a simple low poly scene. Render is warped and deformed

Tags: modeling, rendering

Just re-learning and created a low poly scene to render. For some reason, it is coming out pretty warped and deformed. My books array not appearing correctly. Tv screen is half showing. wall and lighting seems really bad. and the blinds too.

I am on a 2017 macbook pro with Radeon Pro 560 4 GB & Intel HD Graphics 630 1536 MB. It has a quad core as well..

Here is the image:

[image]

Here is the project file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-lSe9MND1Tl0ez3lgN-F91UytQ8HBnHY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi. In future, please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Subdivision Surface Modifier attached to your room, with the number of subdivisions set to 0 for the preview, but 2 for the render. If you want the render to be the same as the preview, turn down the number of subdivisions for the render. However, if 0 subdivisions is what you like the look of, you might not need the modifier at all, or if you still need the "floor" subdivided, consider using "Simple", as opposed to "Catmull-Clark".

[image: SubDiv]

Comment: Thanks so much, Christopher!! Worked, appreciate it. I must have added that modifier by mistake. I'm not even sure what subdivisions are for or why I would want them for my wall or floor... Thanks so much though, I thought it may have been an issue with my CPU rendering.

Comment: Subdivision Surface modifier is used to add virtual faces to a low-poly object in order to make it look smoother, as the faces are only virtual the advantage is that you can keep your object low-poly, which makes it easier to work with and keep your file lighter